# Duas ações na mesma View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Possuo uma View onde retorno os dados de um usuário, e necessito chamar uma outra view, para salvar dados, através de um modal.
O problema, é que são duas Views de controllers diferentes, então ao chamar, por meio de uma **PartialView** eu recebo um erro de declaração.

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities.Usuario', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities.Divergente'.
```

Minha index:

```
@model PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities.Usuario
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Relatar Divergência
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Divergente/Relatar.cshtml")
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--ABAS-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills faq-cat-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionA">Pessoal</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionD">Documentos</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionB">Endereço</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionC">Dados Profissionais</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                    <br /><br />
                    @Html.Partial("_DadosPessoais")
                </div>
                <div id="sectionB" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <br /><br />
                    @Html.Partial("_Endereco")
                </div>
                <div id="sectionC" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <br /><br />
                    @Html.Partial("_DadosProfissionais")
                </div>
                <div id="sectionD" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <br /><br />
                    @Html.Partial("_Documentos")
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




    <div class="container body-content">

        <hr />
        <div align="center">
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Portal RH - <a href="http://www.vilavelha.es.gov.br" target="_blank">Prefeitura Municipal de Vila Velha</a></p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

A View que preciso chamar através do modal:

```
@model PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities.Divergente

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @TempData["Mensagem"]
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h5><strong>Dependente(s)</strong></h5>
                </div>

                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <th>CAMPO</th>
                            <th>INFORMAÇÃO CORRETA</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" align="center">DADOS PESSOAIS</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" class="cb" data-id="nmMae"></td>
                            <td> Data de Nascimento</td>
                            <td><input type="text" data-id="nmMae" disabled class="form-control" name="nmMae"></td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Só adicionando, eu possuo as duas páginas funcionando perfeitamente( em cada view separada), necessito apenas que uma apareça em um modal, na mesma página.

A partial, é um model diferente, com a funcionalidade do usuário salvar no banco, alguma divergência em suas informações, para o administrador revisar e alterar, caso esteja correto. As entidades Usuario e Divergente não possuem nenhum relacionamento, preciso apenas mostrar através de um Modal, para deixar a aplicação mais fácil de ser usada pelo usuário.

Só adicionando, eu possuo as duas páginas funcionando perfeitamente( em cada view separada), necessito apenas que uma apareça em um modal, na mesma página.

Estou tentando fazer da forma correta? Ou existe outra maneira de obter o mesmo resultado?

Comment: As informações que serão exibidas em `PartialView` estão em qual `Model`?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Editei a pergunta, com os models em suas determinadas Views

Comment: Ainda não entendi. `Index` tem `Divergente` como `Model`. A `Partial` também?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Não. A Index possui Usuário como Model, e a partial possui Divergente.
Preciso mostrar as duas na mesma view, apenas para ficar mais fácil do usuário utilizar a aplicação.

Comment: E qual a relação de `Usuario` com `Divergente`, se há alguma?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Nenhuma. O que estou querendo fazer é que quando a pessoa clicar no botão **RELATAR DIVERGÊNCIA** abra um *modal* com a view "Divergente", para o usuário poder edita-lá.
Pois do jeito que está, ele é redirecionado para outra página.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supondo que a Modal já está devidamente escondida, a seguinte declaração deve resolver:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Divergente/Relatar.cshtml", new Divergente())
</div>
```

Atualize seu `@Html.BeginForm()` de dentro da Modal para receber parâmetros da `action` do `form`. Do jeito em que está, o `form` pode ser preenchido errado.

Não sei para onde irá o formulário, mas vou supor que é a `Action Incluir` de `DivergenteController`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Incluir", "Divergente")) { ... }
```

Comment: Agora que notei algo curioso, a PartialView dele não utiliza a @model, vai entender.

Comment: Era isso mesmo que estava precisando.
Mas poderia explicar melhor a parte do **@Html.BeginForm()**? Não entendi onde devo alterar.

Comment: O `@Html.BeginForm()` tem algumas sobreescritas, uma delas lhe permite informar o `actionName` e a `controllerName`, no seu caso é interresante informar estes valores para que o formulario seja recebido pelo Action certa.

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado. Era exatamente o que precisava

Answer (score 1):

A sua `View` está a utilizar uma `Model` do Tipo `PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities.Usuario`, porém a sua `PartialView` está esperando uma `Model` do Tipo `PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities.Divergente`.
Como você não especificou a `Model` a ser passada pela sua `View` para a `PartialView`, ele está a passar a sua propria `Model` para ser compatilhada com a `PartialView`.

Então tudo que precisa é passar uma `Model` do tipo `PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities.Divergente` para a sua `PartialView`.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(...) 
{
    ...
    var divergente = default(Divergente);
    divergente = this.GetDivergente();
    ViewBag.Divergente = divergente;
    ...
}

public Divergente GetDivergente()
{
    ...
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Divergente/Relatar.cshtml", ViewBag.Divergente as PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities.Divergente);
```

Comment: Esqueci de comentar que possui um **@model PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities.Usuario** em minha view Index. ela aceita dois *@models*?

Comment: e o **@model PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities.Divergente** eu já possuo em minha partial

Comment: @Renaldo, `@model` é uma declaração do model que a `View`/`PartialView` espera receber. Como na `PartialView` você declarou que iria usar uma Model do tipo `Divergente`, então a sua `View` precisa passar um objeto do tipo `Divergente` como Model para a sua `PartialView`

Comment: Caso o seu objeto `Usuario` possua como propriedade do tipo `Divergente`, você pode chamar a sua `View` da seguinte forma: `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Divergente/Relatar.cshtml", Model.Divergente);`, caso contrario, ainda na sua controle você precisará salvar um objeto `Divergente` na sua `ViewBag`, e utilizar a mesma para chamar a `PartialView`

Comment: Divergente é uma outra classe, onde não possui relacionamento com o Usuário. Apenas preciso mostrar ela em um modal, para ficar mais fácil do usuário utilizar esta funcionalidade

Comment: atualizei a resposta para utilizar uma ViewBag.

Comment: Com esse código, estou recebendo um erro no **this.GetDivergente**, como se não existisse.

Comment: você precisa implementar este método.